# Password change not sticking for local administrator account

Tags: windows-7, password-management, bartpe

I change the password for the local administrator account while logged in as the administrator, and the passwords stays if I log-off and log-on, but when I restart, it changes back to the previous password.

- "User cannot change password" is unchecked
- I do not believe there is any software that is reverting windows back to a previous image since that is the only change that is not sticking
- The last password change that stayed used: http://www.kood.org/windows-password-renew/ from Bart PE.

The OS is Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Windows 7 Enterprise, are you on a company domain/network?

The IT staff may have scripting/domain preferences in place to (re)set the local Administrator password on Startup:

Some reference info is available in this MS TechNet thread [Change Local Administrator Password thru GPO](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/b1e94909-bb0b-4e10-83a0-cd7812dfe073/):

> 1. **There is a Group Policy Preference (GPP) that can do it for you.** Changing the local Administrator password on domain members has become
>    pretty easy with the advent of Group Policy Preferences...
> 2. **You can script it.**  This script will change your local Administrators passwords to the one you specify. (Note that you'll need to encrypt this one using Microsoft script encrypter if your users shouldn't be able to read it in clear text.)...